# .NET Application Developer uber Framework

Tags: .net, frameworks

I am looking for recommendations on an application developer framework for Visual Studio. A cursory investigation has identified products such as Strataframe, Mere Mortals, CSLA, Deklarit, xEpressApp, Habanero, Spring.Net, etc. What do you recommend, based on your developer experience?

Some of the key requirements are that the framework needs to provide the object/relational DB mapping but also 'build' the UI which accesses the data. The UI builder should allow us customize the screen/page at design time (based on config parameters) such that the programmer is presented with a 'branded' flavor of the form. Obviously, the framework must integrate with .NET Visual Studio and any of the generated code must be customizable or provide hooks for customizing. Not only must it support an n-tier architecture (I think this is probably a given) but it would be nice if the framework also conceptualizes the typically deployment stratas of dev/test/prod. I am not looking for a web/browser based framework - this is strictly in-house behind the firewall business apps.

As background, we are converting from a Visual Foxpro environment which has a custom-developed framework making extensive use of builders.

Answer (score 1):

CSLA is none of that so I would cross it off your list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning Habanero right now and it fits your description pretty well. It comes with a utility called Fire Starter which eases the learning curve a bit. It's heavily influenced by Agile and Domain Driven development. I've not tried it with an existing project but for a new project it has a very simple workflow.

1. Define your classes, property validation, relationships and UI in Fire Starter.
2. Generate the code and forms.
3. Open created solution in either VisualStudio or SharpDevelop
4. Modify

It uses its own UI abstraction layer so it can target both WinForms and ASP.NET. The generated UI reminds me of Nake Objects architectural pattern except its generated at design time so you can modify it.

I'm really a novice with Habanero so I can't tell you too much more than that. I'd check out their wiki and forums for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I love DevExpress components and Framework

Answer (score 0):

Deklarit has ceased being sold as of 1st Sept 2010, leaving me and a lot of others quite annoyed!

There is Sculpture/S-Expert (www.dawliasoft.com), nhydrate.codeplex.com, t4csla.codeplex.com and Vidyano.

And many many others

What did you decide on?